# Removing specific characters from string

Tags: python, nlp

I am new to NLP and trying to do some pre-processing steps on my data for a classification task. I have already done most of the cleaning but there  still are some special characters within the text that I am now trying to remove.

The text is in a Dataframe and is already tokenized and lemmatized, converted to lowercase, with no stopwords and no punctuation. 
Each text record is represented by a list of words.

```
['â€‹â€˜the', 'redwood', 'massacreâ€™', 'five', 'adventurous', 'friend', 'visiting', 'legendary', 'murder', 'site', 'redwood', 'hallmark', 'exciting', 'thrilling', 'camping', 'weekend', 'away', 'soon', 'discover', 'theyâ€™re', 'people', 'mysterious', 'location', 'fun', 'camping', 'expedition', 'soon', 'turn', 'nightmare', 'sadistically', 'stalked', 'mysterious', 'unseen', 'killer']
```

I tried the following code and other solutions as well but I can't understand why the output splits the words into single letters instead of just removing the special character, leaving the words in a compact format.

```
def remove_character(text):
    new_text=[word.replace('€','') for word in text]
    return new_text

df["Column_name"]=df["Column_name"].apply(lambda x:remove_character(x))
```

After applying the function this is the output on the same text record:

```
"['[', ""'"", 'â', '', '‹', 'â', '', '˜', 't', 'h', 'e', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'r', 'e', 'd', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'd', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'm', 'a', 's', 's', 'a', 'c', 'r', 'e', 'â', '', '™', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'f', 'i', 'v', 'e', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'a', 'd', 'v', 'e', 'n', 't', 'u', 'r', 'o', 'u', 's', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'f', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'n', 'd', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'v', 'i', 's', 'i', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'l', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'r', 'y', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'm', 'u', 'r', 'd', 'e', 'r', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 's', 'i', 't', 'e', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'r', 'e', 'd', 'w', 'o', 'o', 'd', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'h', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'k', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'e', 'x', 'c', 'i', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 't', 'h', 'r', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'g', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'c', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'g', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'w', 'e', 'e', 'k', 'e', 'n', 'd', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'a', 'w', 'a', 'y', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 's', 'o', 'o', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'd', 'i', 's', 'c', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 't', 'h', 'e', 'y', 'â', '', '™', 'r', 'e', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'p', 'e', 'o', 'p', 'l', 'e', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'm', 'y', 's', 't', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'l', 'o', 'c', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'f', 'u', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'c', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'g', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'e', 'x', 'p', 'e', 'd', 'i', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 's', 'o', 'o', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 't', 'u', 'r', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'n', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'e', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 's', 'a', 'd', 'i', 's', 't', 'i', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'y', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 's', 't', 'a', 'l', 'k', 'e', 'd', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'm', 'y', 's', 't', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'u', 'n', 's', 'e', 'e', 'n', ""'"", ',', ' ', ""'"", 'k', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'r', ""'"", ']']"
```

Comment: You are looking at mangled UTF-8. The proper fix is to correct whatever is mangling these strings. In brief, it's looking like something is labelling UTF-8 as Latin-1 (or some other 8-bit legacy character set) earlier in your processing. This is a very common FAQ.

Comment: it looks like you don't have list with words in every cell in DF but single word in every cell in DF and you shouldn't use `for`-loop which split word into chars. Rather use `.apply(lambda x: x.replace('€','') )` or maybe even with `.str` - `.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('€','') )`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have single words in cells like this

```
$ df.head()

   Column_name
0    â€‹â€˜the
1      redwood
2  massacreâ€™
3         five
4  adventurous
```

so you shouldn't use `for word in text` which will split word into chars - it will work like `for char in text`.

You should use only `replace()` in `apply()` which will run it with every cell (similar to `for`-loop)

```
df["Column_name"] = df["Column_name"].apply(lambda word: word.replace('€',''))
```

---

Minimal working example (so everyone can copy and run it)

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_character(text):
    return [word.replace('€', '') for word in text]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_name': ['â€‹â€˜the', 'redwood', 'massacreâ€™', 'five', 'adventurous', 'friend', 'visiting', 'legendary', 'murder', 'site', 'redwood', 'hallmark', 'exciting', 'thrilling', 'camping', 'weekend', 'away', 'soon', 'discover', 'theyâ€™re', 'people', 'mysterious', 'location', 'fun', 'camping', 'expedition', 'soon', 'turn', 'nightmare', 'sadistically', 'stalked', 'mysterious', 'unseen', 'killer']})

print(df.head())

df["Column_name"] = df["Column_name"].apply(lambda word: word.replace('€',''))
#df["Column_name"] = df["Column_name"].apply(lambda x:remove_character(x))

print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove_character` function should return a string rather than a list. However, `pandas` includes the `str` accessor on a `Series` to perform operations [on strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str) so another option you can use is

```
df["Column_name"] = df["Column_name"].str.replace('€','')
```

(no need to use `apply`)